# How to prove this inequalityy?

Tags: inequality

It's kinda dumb question but I literally struggle to prove $$a^2\leq \frac{\sqrt{a^8+4a^7+4a^6}}{a} \text{ for } a\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$$

It is true for $a=\frac{1}{2}$ but I don't think that it's enough to show the inequality for $a=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Cross multiply and square both sides

Comment: That inequality is true for all $a>0$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! To improve your post and let us understand how can we help you, can you please provide context for the problem? Where did you encountered it? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Because of $a>0$ one can divide both sides by $a^2$ and put $a^3$ under root ($a^6$). Then one needs to prove $\sqrt{a^2+4a+4}\geq 1$. $a+2>0 \Rightarrow \sqrt{a^2+4a+4}=a+2$ which is greater than 1 for $a>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{a^8+4a^7+4a^6}}{a}
&= \sqrt{a^6+4a^5+4a^4} \\
&= a^2\sqrt{a^2+4a+4} \\
&= a^2\sqrt{(a+2)^2} \\
&= a^2(a+2) \\
&\geqslant a^2
\end{align}$$
where the last line holds for $a+2 \geqslant 1$ which is the case.

- The 1st line shortens out $a$, i.e. $a^2$ under the square root.
- The 2nd line drags $a^4$ out of the quare root, which becomes $a^2$ outside.
- The 4th line is rules for the square root and due to $a+2\geqslant 0$.

Comment: Omg thank you! I tried so much but I did not think of factoring $a$ out of the square root and using the rules and binomial formla

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\sqrt{a^8+4a^7+4a^6}}{a}\ge \frac{\sqrt{a^6}}{a}=a^2  $